# how the background color changes when hovering the cursor over certain elements

Tags: typescript, web, tailwind-css

i am working on a spotify clone but I can't figure out how to change top color when hovering over other elements.
for now i have just the Liked songs that i want to change when hovering on it i want the background to change when hovering over one child , i just need it to change to be gradient from blue instead those are the files i am using

Header.tsx

```
"use client"

import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import {twMerge} from "tailwind-merge";
import {RxCaretLeft, RxCaretRight} from "react-icons/rx";
import {HiHome} from "react-icons/hi";
import {BiSearch} from "react-icons/bi";
import Button from "./Button";

interface HeaderProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
    className?: string
}
const Header:React.FC<HeaderProps> = ({children, className}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const handleLogout = () => { }
    return (
        <div className={twMerge('h-fit bg-gradient-to-b from-emerald-800 p-6',className)}>
            <div className='w-full mb-4 flex items-center justify-between'>
                <div className='hidden md:flex gap-x-2 items-center'>
                    <button className='rounded-full bg-black flex items-center justify-center hover:opacity-75 transition' onClick={() => router.back()}>
                          <RxCaretLeft size={35} className = 'text-white' />
                    </button>
                    <button className='rounded-full bg-black flex items-center justify-center hover:opacity-75 transition' onClick={() => router.forward()}>
                        <RxCaretRight size={35} className = 'text-white' />
                    </button>

                </div>
                <div className='flex md:hidden gap-x-2 items-center'>
                    <button className='rounded-full p-2 bg-white flex justify-center hover:opacity-75 items-center transition'>
                        <HiHome size={20} className = 'text-black' />
                    </button>
                    <button className='rounded-full p-2 bg-white flex justify-center hover:opacity-75 items-center transition'>
                        <BiSearch size={20} className = 'text-black' />
                    </button>

                </div>
                <div className='flex justify-between items-center gap-x-4'>
                    <>
                        <div>
                            <Button className='bg-transparent text-neutral-300 font-medium' onClick={()=>{}}>
                                Sign up
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Button className='bg-white px-6 py-2' onClick={()=>{}}>
                                Log in
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </>
                </div>
            </div>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

and this is

page.tsx

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import ListItem from "@/components/ListItem";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-neutral-900 rounded-lg h-full w-full overflow-y-auto overflow-hidden'>
      <Header>
        <div className='mb-2'>
            <h1 className='text-white text-3xl font-semibold'>
                Welcome back
            </h1>
//this div is the one i want to change when hover 

            <div className='grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-4 gap-3 mt-4'>
                <ListItem image='/images/liked.png' name='Liked Songs' href='liked'/>

            </div>

        </div>
      </Header>
        <div className='px-6 mt-2 mb-7'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
                <h1 className='text-white text-3xl font-semibold'>
                    New Releases
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                List of Songs
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

just note that i am a beginner in tailwind so...